# Display data in a nested table in angular

Tags: lightning-aura-components, angularjs

I am using Lightning in salesforce along with angular. I have below object

```
[{"day":"Wednesday, June 28th 2017"},{"day":"Thursday, June 29th 2017"},{"day":"Friday, June 30th 2017"},{"day":"Saturday, July 1st 2017"},{"day":"Sunday, July 2nd 2017"}]
```

I want to display this inside a nested table I tried below code.

```
<table ng-app="salesApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <tr ng-repeat="r in rows">
<td>
<table><tr><td>{{r.day}}</td></tr></table>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

Since I have nested table I guess I am losing the row data. I cannot put the ng-repeat inside the nested table so it has to be on the outer table. Any solution for this?

Comment: I would expect that to render. Check the JavaScript console for errors. See [Requirements Checklist](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Requirements_Checklist) for cautions about mixing Lightning and Angular. Doesn't make much sense (as their capabilities overlap/interfere) unless you already have a large amount of Angular code already written.

Comment: If I put r.day in outer table then it works fine. So may be its an issue where angular may be creating its own view for the new table?

Comment: Well `ng-repeat` duplicates the DOM element and its nested elements so not sure why the nested table makes a difference.

Comment: This does render in jsfiddle - so yeah, mixing angular + lightning, not a good idea. http://jsfiddle.net/gp6vgtt4/1/